# Swift Package Manager: how do I archive?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have created a Swift Package via Xcode. This packaged defines a library:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "SPMBasedA",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "SPMBasedA",
            type: .static,
            targets: ["SPMBasedA"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "SPMBasedA")
    ]
)
```

The scheme is well displayed in Xcode and project seems to compile properly, but whenever I archive, there are no products in the exported archive. Why is that, what am I doing wrong? How do I make the build artifacts appear? Is it related to `SKIP_INSTALL`? If so, how do I disable it in SPM?

Comment: Perhaps you need a [binary target](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-binary-frameworks-as-swift-packages)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson from what I'm gathering, this is a way to declare an existing .framework as a dependency. What I need is to create a .framework from source code. I.e. vice-versa.